# smtp mutt delay sending email

Tags: mutt

We use smtp for authentication at the new office I work at.  So my muttrc contains smtp_url and smtp_pass configuration.  When I send email, I have to wait for the authentication to complete before I can do other stuff.

In the past for send delays, I've had success with:

```
set sendmail_wait=-1
```

However, this doesn't seem to apply to the smtp authentication.  The two second delay is annoying.

Does anyone know how to background the authentication?